# Running 'terragrunt apply' on an EC2 Instance housed in a No Internet Environment

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

I have been trying to set up my Terragrunt EC2 environment in a no/very limited internet setting.

**Current Setup:**

- AWS network firewall that whitelists domains to allow traffic, and most internet traffic is blocked excepted a few domains.
- EC2 instance where I run the terragrunt code, it has an instance profile that can assume the role in `providers`
- VPC endpoints set up for sts, s3, dynamodb, codeartifact etc
- All credentials (assumed role etc) work and have been verified

**Remote State and Providers File**

```
remote_state {
  backend = "s3"
  generate = { 
    path      = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }
  config = { 
    bucket = "***"

    key = "${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "ap-southeast-1" 
    encrypt        = true
    dynamodb_table = "***"
  }
}

# Dynamically changes the role depending on which account is being modified
generate "providers" {
  path      = "providers.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite"

  contents  = <<EOF
provider "aws" {
  region = "${local.env_vars.locals.aws_region}"
  assume_role {
    role_arn    = "arn:aws:iam::$***"
  endpoints {
    sts = "https://sts.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com" 
    s3 = "https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com" 
    dynamodb = "https://dynamodb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
  }
}
EOF
}
```

**With Internet (Turning off the firewall):**

- I am able to run all the terragrunt commands

**Without Internet**

- I *only* allow "registry.terraform.io" to pass the firewall
- I am able to assume the role listed in `providers` via aws sts assume-role, and I can list the tables in dynamodb and files in the s3 bucket
- I am able to run `terragrunt init` on my EC2 instance with the instance profile, I assume terragrunt does use the correct sts_endpoint
- However when I run `terragrunt apply`, it hangs at the stage `DEBU[0022] Running command: terraform plan prefix=[***]
- In my CloudTrail I do see that Terragrunt has assumed the username `aws-go-sdk-1660077597688447480` for the event `GetCallerIdentity`, so I think the provider is able to assume the role that was declared in the `providers` block
- I tried adding custom endpoints for `sts`, `s3`, and `dynamodb`, but it still hangs.

I suspect that terraform is still trying to use the internet when making the AWS SDK calls, which leads to `terragrunt apply` being stuck.

- Is there a comprehensive list of endpoints I need to custom add, or a list of domains I should whitelist to be able to run `terragrunt apply`?

Comment: I'm guessing Terraform is still trying to get to the public endpoints. You can define service endpoints in the AWS provider configuration: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/custom-service-endpoints.

Comment: I did try by adding the endpoints into the providers block `  endpoints {
    sts = "https://sts.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com" 
    s3 = "https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com" 
    dynamodb = "https://dynamodb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
  }` But I suspect that the endpoints are not sufficient, so was wondering if people know what comprehensive list of endpoints are required, or if there are additional flags to add

Comment: Are you using `terragrunt apply` only or you are adding some switches like `run-all`?

Comment: I am using `terragrunt apply`, running run-all should be the same since it loops a `terragrunt apply` no?

Comment: Well, I've hit an issue in a CI/CD pipeline with `run-all` hence my question.

Comment: Were you able to run a CI/CD pipeline without internet access?

Comment: Nah, it was an issue between an older version of terragrunt and newer version of Terraform, because it seems that if the output Terraform provides changes, run-all can fail. That was my conclusion at least.

Comment: Try to turn on terraform debug to see exactly what terraform tries to do - https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging

Answer (score 1):

I set the environment variable `TF_LOG` to `debug`, and besides the `registry.terraform.io` domain, I was able to gather these ones:

- github.com

```
2022-08-18T15:33:03.106-0600 [DEBUG] using github.com/hashicorp/go-tfe v1.0.0
2022-08-18T15:33:03.106-0600 [DEBUG] using github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2 v2.12.0
2022-08-18T15:33:03.106-0600 [DEBUG] using github.com/hashicorp/terraform-config-inspect v0.0.0-20210209133302-4fd17a0faac2
2022-08-18T15:33:03.106-0600 [DEBUG] using github.com/hashicorp/terraform-svchost v0.0.0-20200729002733-f050f53b9734
```

- sts.region.amazonaws.com
- resource.region.amazonaws.com

You'll want to add those domains to your whitelist in the firewall settings, something like `*.region.amazonaws.com` should do the trick, of course, you can be more restrictive, and rather than use a wildcard, you can specify the exact resource.

For reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: Hi Javier, yes you pointed me in the right direction. After more investigation, it turns out that there are some endpoints such as sts where terragrunt does not call the regional endpoints (even after specifying not sure why), and endpoints like iam where there are no regional endpoints. So I had to whitelist sts.amazonaws.com and iam.amazonaws.com and now it works!

Comment: Glad it’s working now! The thing is that some AWS resources like IAM aren’t regional. I’ve added the AWS documentation where they mention it.